# Label For radio buttons does not work in popup created using jquery modal popup

Tags: jquery, html

THis sounds more like an html issue than jquery and I hope someone could help me with this.

I have a hidden div containing radio buttons which has Label For tag. This works great on the page (I tested by removing hidden property from the div), but when I pull that div content out of on the modal popup created using jquery my Label For does not work on a popup. It seems when I click on the label from my modal window it clicks the appropriate radio on parent page but not the one on modal window.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Maybe you could show us some code? jsfiddle.net

Comment: From your last sentence (before your thanks) it sounds like you have the radio buttons repeated - do they have the same ids?

Comment: Here's my code:

<input type="radio" name="rdoReason" id="6" Value="6" alt="No further verbal contact"><Label FOR="6" alt="No further verbal contact"">No further verbal contact</Label>
<input type="radio" name="rdoReason" id="9" Value="9" alt="Phone disconnected"><Label FOR="9" alt="Phone disconnected"> Phone disconnected</Label>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well... The good old fashion way of connecting a label to an input element would be to give the label a `for` attribute equal to the `id` of the input element.

```
<label for="acceptEmail" >Accept emails</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="acceptEmail" />
```

You can also get the same result by placing the input element *inside* the label.

```
<label>Accept emails
  <input type="checkbox" id="acceptEmail" />
</label>
```

Comment: Thanks Lix. That's how I have my Label For. The problem is it works on a regular html page but not on a modal window which is intantiated from the same page.

Comment: There shouldn't be a difference as it is all HTML and *should* behave the same way... Perhaps you have some JavaScript interfering with the default behavior or perhaps your HMTL is malformed in some way...

Comment: Thanks. I figured it out and yes I had javascript which was interfering. My Modal window code was just appending my hidden div contents to modal div instead of removing from original div, so I had 2 instances of same radio buttons on a page.

Answer (score 0):

I added a span tag next to the input with a class="text"

```
            <label>
                <input type="radio" name="rr"  />
                <span class="text">&nbsp;</span>
            </label>
```